# Trying to use MySQL to return user information

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Current code:

```
<?php

session_start();

if ($_SESSION['username']) {
    echo "Signed in as " . "$_SESSION[username]" . "<br />" . "<a href='logout.php'>Log         out</a>";

    //Get user info.

    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$_SESSION[username]");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results) {
        $db_username = $row['username'];
        echo $db_username;
    }
}    

else {
    echo "Log in";
}

?>
```

Unfortunately  I'm getting errors when returning the values that MySQL is supposed to be getting. Any idea why?

Comment: `...username=$_SESSION[username]` Looks wrong to me, `username='$_SESSION[username]'` Looks better

Comment: Advice: When you get an error message please insert it into your question. This makes it easier to help you!

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions - ***they are deprecated and will be removed!***. Use `mysqli` or PDO instead. (Incidentally, PDO's parameterised queries might solve your problem.)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use single quote around value in query

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$_SESSION[username]}'");
                                                ^^                   ^^
```

Also stop using `mysql_*` functions they are deprecated, Use `MySQLi` OR `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong since it contains PHP variables not enclosed in single quotes or curly braces.
You can rewrite the query as follows:

With braces:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username={$_SESSION[username]}");`
```

Or with single quotes:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]'");
```